# Como mandar un mensaje al intentar eliminar un registro que tiene relacion de foreign key?

Tags: java, mysql, validación

Lo que que necesito es que cuando el usuario presione el boton eliminar el registro, no me permita eliminar si es que tiene relación con otra tabla, es decir, tengo una tabla grupo_cod, relacionada con otra que se llama items, al momento de eliminar un registro grupo_cod debo verificar si tiene una relación en items.. de ser así, enviar un mensaje al usuario, de lo contrario eliminarlo..

```
if(operacion=="eliminar"){
        int a =JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Esta seguro que dese eliminar", "Eliminar", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
         if(a==JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
        con.conectar();

        con.ejecutarSentencia("delete from grupos where gru_cod="+txt_id.getText());
        con.CerrarConexion();
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Eliminado con exito");
       btn_cancelarActionPerformed(null);                     

    }
```

este es el codigo que utilizo para eliminar, lo que necesito es que haga tipo una comparacion para que sepa que si el registro se esta utilizando en otra tabla no elimine y envie un sms

Comment: Hola Vale, bienvenido al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio!. Para que obtengas buenas respuestas formula una buena pregunta, para esto te sugiero leer [ask], saludos!

Comment: Vale mira los links que te paso Jorge. A esta pregunta le falta informacion sobre que base de datos, que lenguaje, y que intentaste y no anduvo hasta ahora.

Comment: Base de Datos MySql Lenguaje Java